# how to fast loading video from firebase storage in flutter application

Tags: flutter, firebase, video-streaming, firebase-storage

Any one can explain my query
**Why Firebase storage slow working ?**
when we upload a video in firebase storage from the app , and we play video in flutter video player using downloading URL. it take 7 to 8 sec for play video.
but we directly put a another server hosted video URL in firebase storage ,then play in video player it take 2 to 3 sec.

**Why & How can we achieve fast loading from firebase storage in application.**

Thanks for reach the post & suggestion.

Comment: The rate of download is not a matter of the code you write.  It's a matter of the speed of the network between the computer making the request and the Google Cloud server that sends the data.  You have no control over that in your app code.  The best you can do in your project is choose a cloud region that's close to the computer making the request.

Comment: This question is way too vague; "why isn't my app fast" cannot be answered here on SO without the supporting code. I agree with @DougStevenson; however, if you've just got some bad coding it could also cause laggy video displays. It's not really clear what this means - *we directly put a another server hosted video URL in firebase storage* - as Firebase storage is not really the right place to store URL's - those would be stored in Firestore or RTDB. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)